# Get record that is not equal to true in sql?

Tags: sql

I want to get all records  that have "isdirectPO" equal to not true and show all other that are null or false
but this line of code does not work it return no line 
table have 323 records 1 is true and others are null

```
select * from PurchaseOrder where isdirectPO !=1
```

Comment: isdirectPO data type please?

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from PurchaseOrder where isdirectPO !=1 OR (isdirectPO IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try like below

```
select * from PurchaseOrder where isdirectPO is null or isdirectPO=false
```

it seems `isdirectPO`  is `int` data type in that case false mean 0 so you can use

```
select * from PurchaseOrder where isdirectPO is null or isdirectPO=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below the query to get the results as per your requirement.

```
select * from PurchaseOrder where (isdirectPO =0 OR isdirectPO IS NULL)
```